How to disable "Keep these display settings?" prompt in Windows 11 when switching to another display
Background / problem
this is an annoying issue I'm experiencing. I have an external hdmi monitor connection to my Windows 11 machine and whenever I close the lid and then reopen it, I have to edit my projection settings again:

It then further prompts me to verify that I want this display setting that I have just set.

Desired result
ideally, the I want to happen is to primarily only use the monitor except for certain situations. and normally I want the screen of the device to be off instead of duplicated. whenever I close the lid nothing happens; fine. however, whenever I open the lid, instead of maintaining the projection onto 2, it reverts automatically back to Duplicate. and then I have to open Display settings, select 2, and (just to slap me in the face again) it gives me the annoying validation pop up.
also don't even bother telling me to edit the "choose what happens when you close the lid" option to avoid the issue in the first place (it happens when I OPEN the lid). you can see I already have it set:

Summary

how do I make it quit at will edit my setting when opening the lid
how do I make it stfu and just switch the settings without bichin about if that's definitely the thing I want.

Other information
Driver
My drivers have always been fully up to date
Driver version: 32.0.11027.1003

Windows Version
Windows 23H2 (OS Build 22631.4602)

As per our code of conduct, please don't swear.
